# Upgrading to .NET 4.0 causes Temporary ASP.NET Files to prevent breakpoints from working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net-4.0

Before I open my solution, I go into the 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' folder and delete its contents. I set a breakpoint and start debugging and all is right with the world. However, if I stop debugging, then start again it gives me the 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.' error. To remedy this, I have to close Visual Studio, delete the temporary files then reopen my solution. It's a huge pain and it didn't start until the site was upgraded to .NET 4.0, these temporary files will also sometimes just annihilate the code and break everything until they're deleted.

I've tried rebuilding the solution, restarting IIS, stopping IIS before I delete the temporary files and then restarting it, setting up a local symbols cache, everything I could possibly find on here and on Google and they still continue to exist and break everything. Is there a way to force Visual Studio to delete these things when debugging stops or something? Or is there possibly something else going on here?

Comment: What about "Clean Solution"?

Comment: That option is not available for my solution.

Comment: @AbaddonVH - I assume this is a Web Site project rather than a Web Application Project, correct?  Web Site projects are just evil, and shouldn't be used.  I know, that's not a solution for you.. But I would suggest converting it to a Web Application project as soon as you can.

Comment: Indeed it is a Web Site project, and as you said, converting is not an option for me. I'm simply one of a number of people working on this site and I doubt the lead dev will agree to convert it.

Comment: Then sack the dev lead, obviously has no idea!! Does anyone else in your team have this issue? If not have they done something different to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever crazy reason, installing some Windows updates made all my problems go away. No idea what the correlation was but I'm no longer experiencing this issue.